# worship leader range loss and excessive vocal fry

Tags: vocal-fry

I am experiencing vocal fry in my upper register that I did not use to have. I am a bass but leading worship generally puts me outside of my range sometimes significantly. I always make sure to relax and support correctly what I sing and I hydrate like a maniac. At the end of the day I still end up with a sore throat and my voice sounds like trash. I am worried that I am being pushed too hard and am causing damage. Is this something that I can eventually train through, or do I seriously need to consider taking some vocal rest to see if that helps? I'm also experiencing loss of range at the top of my register not the bottom. Any advice would be helpful at this point.

Comment: Yikes, loss of range has generally been permanent in my experience. My mom reports losing her upper range decades ago and never getting it back, and my range has been dropping for over a decade (slowly lose top notes and gain bottom notes). Warm-ups only temporarily increase my upper range, and only seem to boost it by a whole tone at most.

Answer (score 3):

Just like every other art of our bodies, those which produce sound deteriorate over time. Even greats like Elvis (!) needed to drop some songs a couple of keys in later life, and he is not alone.

Simple solution - sing in a range which suits your voice, rather than straining, which will only exacerbate the problem - maybe even to the permanent damage point. Not good. So, changes of keys with high tessitura are in order. Just hope your accompanist/s will cope!

Use a mic, learn the techniques we have for singing more gently - there really should be no need to belt out anything.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an evaluation by an otolaryngologist, if possible one with a specialized practice in voice medicine.  While it is true that changes of this sort are unavoidable with aging, it's also possible that there is a contributing factor that you *can* manage.  A common one is gastroesophageal reflux, which can be managed relatively effectively in many cases.  Another possible factor in voice changes is neurological.

If there is an underlying cause of these changes, it is unlikely to affect only your voice, so you will probably want to identify any such cause and, if possible, address it as early as possible.

If no underlying cause can be found, you can probably still improve your lot.  An otolaryngologist can help with treatment for your symptoms.  A voice teacher, preferably an experienced one with a sound training in the science of vocal pedagogy, can help you determine whether your "relax and support correctly" is in fact correct.

Unless I've overlooked it, you haven't mentioned your age.  If you are young, especially if you are in your mid 20s or younger, you may want to consider the possibility that your voice is still maturing and your newfound difficulties arise because of that.  Regardless of your age, you may simply have a voice that is unsuited to leading worship.  The keys chosen for unison singing are nearly always too high for a true bass.  It's a bit like singing *Le veau d'or* from Gounod's *Faust* for 40 minutes straight (in the opera, the two verses with chorus take less than two minutes).

Comment: Im currently 27 I can't remember at what age the voice fully matures. And yes unison singing is very much in unfriendly territory for me.

Comment: I'm over 30, and I swear I'm still gaining bottom notes in my singing range. (I'm also female.)